# “Would have + past participle” in The Scarlet Letter

Tags: conditional-constructions, present-perfect, perfect-constructions

From *[The Scarlet Letter](http://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/127/the-scarlet-letter/2267/chapter-2-the-market-place/):*

> Amongst any other population, or at a later period in the history of New England, the grim  rigidity that petrified the bearded physiognomies of these good people **would have** augured  some awful business in hand.

Would you possibly throw a light on the reason why there has been used ***would have past participle?***

Eventually, do the following A and B mean the same thing?

A.The grim rigidity that petrified the bearded physiognomies of these good people would have augured some awful business in hand **if it had appeared/occurred amongst any other population**, or at a later period in the history of New England.

B. In other words, if the people were anyone other than the early Puritans of Boston, then their grim, rigid demeanor would indicate that something extraordinarily serious and awful was about to happen, like the public execution of a criminal. However (as is explained in the next few sentences), the early Puritans of Boston commonly took on the same grim demeanor when attending to small matters as well as large matters, including whipping a misbehaving child or escorting a drunk Indian out of town.

Comment: @nima Perhaps also insert the first sentence of that novel, so that the reader understands that your excerpt comes from a novel that uses past-tense narrative mode: *"The grass–plot before the jail, in Prison Lane, on a certain summer morning, not less than two centuries ago, was occupied by a pretty large number of the inhabitants of Boston, all with their eyes intently fastened on the iron–clamped oaken door. Amongst any other population, . . ."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase **would have** (in this context) indicates that the following clause describes a [counterfactual situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence#Counterfactual) that did not occur, but "would have" occurred in the past if the condition described previously were true. The part of the sentence before **would have** describes a hypothesis; the part after **would have** describes a consequence of that hypothesis.

In other words, *if* the people were anyone other than the early Puritans of Boston, *then* their grim, rigid demeanor *would* indicate that something extraordinarily serious and awful was about to happen, like the public execution of a criminal. However (as is explained in the next few sentences), the early Puritans of Boston commonly took on the same grim demeanor when attending to small matters as well as large matters, including whipping a misbehaving child or escorting a drunk Indian out of town.

The idea is that the Puritans were very unusual people: they took everything very, very seriously. The postures of their bodies and the looks on their faces became as grim and stiff when they attended to small, commonplace matters, as the postures and looks of other people become when attending to the most serious and awful matters, such as publicly hanging a murderer.

### But why is it “would have + *past participle*”?

Normally **have + *past participle*** means the perfect aspect. Here it means the past tense. The reason for this abuse of the word **have** is that **augured some awful business…** is in the conditional mood, but English has no word that clearly specifies a past-tense conditional mood. If you say **would + *infinitive***, that would suggest that the imagined consequence happens in the present or the future. If you say only **have + *past participle***, that would suggest that the consequence really happened (if the hypothesis were true).

So, in English you say **would have + *infinitive*** to indicate a consequence that, if it had happened, "would have" happened in the past. Yes, this is strange and confusing, because the same construction also fits a consequence in the future. For a brief explanation of why English grammar has these nonsensical and ambiguous constructions, see [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42951).

The reason for saying **would have augured** instead of **would augur** is mainly to reinforce the fact that the story is set in the past. **Would augur** would still be correct. But **would have augured** reinforces the fact that the "grim rigidity" did happen (in the story) even though the auguring didn't.

By the way, **augur** is not a commonly used word today. Today we would might say **imply**.

### The revision

This:

> The grim rigidity that petrified the bearded physiognomies of these good people would have augured some awful business in hand **if it had appeared/occurred amongst any other population** or at a later period in the history of New England.

is perfect. Nathaniel Hawthorne himself could have written it. (Notice that **could have** works just like **would have**. It's another past tense for an imaginary situation, abusing **have** to avoid sounding like the present tense.) I took the liberty of removing a comma after **population**, so the **or** phrase is more clearly governed by the **if**.

Comment: I am still wondering the reason why such a reinforces should be occur:But would have augured reinforces the fact that the "grim rigidity" did happen even though the auguring didn't.

Comment: Or, why the auguring didn't happen?

Comment: @nima I don't think there is any strict rule. Often in language we make words "echo" other words to make the meaning clear, even though it's not strictly necessary. In the story, **would have** makes clear that the imagined auguring "would have" happened in the past (but it didn't). The author wants you to imagine that day in the 1600s in Boston more than he wants you to imagine other times and cultures. He is only bringing up other cultures for a moment to draw a contrast.

Comment: @nima The reason the auguring didn't happen—or, in more modern language, the reason the people's demeanor did not imply that they were about to attend to serious and awful business—is because the Puritans were unusual, extremely serious-minded people. Unlike most people, the Puritans became extremely serious even about relatively minor matters. That's what the paragraph is trying to say.

Comment: So, it seems to say: such a grim rigidity in later period failed to project or augur those bad things, as such a rigidity only belonged to just the time mentioned not after it

Comment: @nima Not quite. (English grammar is hard!) It means that in other times and places, when people have that grim rigidity, it's always because they're attending to something as serious and awful as a public execution. Only in Puritan Boston did that grim rigidity fail to imply that they were attending to similarly serious and awful business. In Puritan Boston, people reached the same level of grim rigidity even about much less important matters.

Comment: why did it fail?

Comment: why did it fail to project or forecast?

Comment: @nima Because the Puritans were very unusual people. They took an extremely serious attitude about almost everything. So, just from seeing their serious attitude, you can't reliably infer that the matter they're attending to is really so important. Maybe it is and maybe it isn't. (Or at least this is what Nathaniel Hawthorne is saying in the story. I've also heard that the real Puritans weren't as stiff and humorless as their depictions in literature suggest.)

Comment: so, as such a rigidity have blind them-- the rigidity made their attitude too bad-- . or, the rigidity belonged to such a bad people failed to distinguish future happenses

Comment: @nima Now I think I see the misunderstanding. The rigidity in the sentence refers to the faces and physical posture of the people, not their general attitude. It's not that a rigid attitude made them blind, it's that their very serious general attitude led them to become grim and physically rigid in the way most people do when attending a public execution, even when attending something of much smaller importance.

Comment: Eventually, now, through your and my profs. invaluable helps, I get my answer.

Comment: I greatly really do appreciate your support and taking time.