# Is there a simple and clear way to explain the difference between past simple and present perfect?

Tags: tense, verbs, past-tense, present-perfect

I read (or do I say "have read"?) many rules for when to use the present perfect. I found them complex and hard to understand (or do I say "have found"?). I am finding it hard to apply these rules in real sentences.

Is there a simple and clear way to explain the difference between past simple and present perfect? If there is a simple explanation, please tell it! If there is no simple explanation, please tell why it is so complicated. Maybe if I knew *why* there is no simple explanation, that would help me understand what work I need to do in order to learn the difference.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because one could write a book on "the real difference" between the two tenses (or aspects).

Comment: Technically, it's a yes-or-no question, so I'll answer it that way. I think it might be helpful to have a short explanation of why it can't be done.

Comment: One main difference is that present-perfect is often used when the speaker wants to indicate or stress that a situation that has started in the past is still important now in the present time or the present conversation. :)

Comment: There are ***lots*** of sentences where you can use either one with the same meaning. There are also lots of sentences where using the wrong one will sound funny. And finally, there are lots of sentences where you can use either one, but the meaning or the emphasis of the sentence will be different.

Comment: I'd been an ESL teacher for 7 years before I realized that there are British/American differences in this area. See, for example https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/british-english-and-american-english .

Comment: @JimReynolds The first example on that page is wrong! Yet another reason this is so complicated: the ever-varying Transatlantic differences are hard to keep track of, even for the presumably well-funded British Council.

Comment: @F.E. _Yes it is_ not _That it be_! - Blackadder :-)

Comment: Though my opinion still stands (that the topic is complicated enough to write a book on that; I wish I had more time to write a longer explanation, which is now unnecessary, why I think a short, simple discussion is not going to be the real answer for learners; I'm glad that Ben Kovitz's discussed that, nicely), I decide to vote to reopen this question, seeing that it's likely that we're going to have more good discussions out of this thread.

Answer (score 17):

### Short answer: Yes

The difference is that the past tense means the action happened at some specific time in the past, and the present perfect means the action happened at an unstated time *during a certain time interval* that started in the past and continued to the present—maybe more than once during that time interval, depending on what you're talking about.

This action occupied the entire time interval from 1997 until now, and will probably continue:

> Brenda has worked at Merriam-Webster since 1997.

This action occurred sometime during the speaker's life so far, perhaps many years ago, perhaps recently, perhaps more than once:

> I have seen war.

This action occurred at the very end of the time interval (the time interval is that of the whole race):

> Jones has won the race!

### Long answer: No

The reason this topic is hopelessly complicated is because reality provides an infinity of  different situations, and what time interval is reasonable to talk about varies for each situation.

For example, the time interval for the following question starts at roughly 11:00 a.m. this morning:

> Have you eaten lunch?

The question literally means, "During the part that has elapsed so far today of the daily time interval when people normally eat lunch, did you eat lunch?" If you already ate lunch, then you probably don't want to go to lunch now; if you did not already eat lunch, then you might be interested in going to lunch with the speaker now. A person wouldn't ask that question after the middle of the afternoon, because that would be too much later than the normal time to eat lunch. The question leads you to think of the time period for lunch as a sort of window of opportunity that is still open, and asks whether that opportunity has already been exercised.

There's another source of endless complexity: the fact that you are referring to a time interval influences the way a listener understands the verb after **have** as well as the other words in the sentence.

For example, this sentence means that Chris performed the duty of phone-answerer last week, and answered the phone many times:

> During the past week, Chris **has answered** the phone.

Using the perfect tense suggests that you might mean that the action fills the entire time interval, so the above sentence leads a listener to understand **answering** as performing a week-long duty to answer the phone whenever it rings. (This would probably be at a business.) Also, it would be strange to speak of a single instance of answering the phone in the present perfect if it happened at some unspecified time during the past week. If Chris answered the phone four days ago, the phone call is surely over by now.

The next sentence probably means that Chris answered the phone once. But it *could* also mean the same as the previous sentence:

> During the past week, Chris **answered** the phone.

The reason it could mean the same as the previous sentence is the time interval is explicitly spelled out, and **answering** can still be understood as performing phone-answering duty, regardless of the tense. The past tense doesn't suggest that the action filled the time interval, so it doesn't suggest the “week-long duty” interpretation as strongly as the present perfect. But the past tense doesn't contradict that interpretation, either.

> I spoke.
>
> I have spoken.

The first of the above sentences just means that you said something. The second one means that you have said everything you have to say, and probably that you don't want to listen to or address any objections. Because the present perfect suggests a time interval that ends at the present moment, it can suggest that an action filling that time interval is now complete and will not continue. Obviously, though, that's not the intended meaning of the earlier example of someone working at Merriam-Webster since 1997.

Here's an example that follows the basic principle plainly, but is still subtle:

> I **wrote** two novels in 2009.
>
> I **have written** two novels. [The time interval is the speaker's whole life so far.]
>
> <strike>I **have written** two novels in 2009.</strike> [Ungrammatical, because 2009 is over. But this would be grammatical if said during 2009.]
>
> I **have written** two novels this year. [This is OK, because this year is still present.]

Yet another use of the present perfect is to establish the time frame for [a news story](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/15/business/capturing-carbon-as-a-byproduct-of-running-a-fuel-cell.html?ref=business). “Until now, most efforts to capture carbon have been expensive, in dollars and in energy.” The past tense (“were expensive”) would mean the same thing, but the present perfect suggests that the rest of the story will describe how that technology is now changing. It leads the reader to expect that the time period covered by the story will be very broad, on the order of years. Beginning [a news story](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/13/business/international-energy-agency-cuts-oil-demand-forecast.html) in the past tense suggests a very short time frame.

You just have to learn through experience to understand why people sometimes want to refer to a time interval rather than just the specific event. And you learn to infer what that time interval is, since it's usually implicit. Eventually it becomes effortless, but no simple rule could ever cover all situations.

Comment: Ben sir, in the above explanation, looking at your sentence of 'During the past week Chris has answered the phone', you say here we are talking about the week the ended and it doesn't extend upto the present. Then, what I don't understand is how we can use present perfect with "During the past week Chris has answered the phone" when we mean the week that ended as we have set a timeframe and hence can't use the present perfect. Please clear the doubt sir.

Thank you.

Comment: @Policewala *Last week* designates a seven-day timeframe which ended in the past, but ***the** past week* and ***the** last week* designate a seven-day timeframe which extends right up to the present.

Comment: But StoneyB,  in his phrase For example, this sentence means that Chris performed the duty of phone-answerer last week, and answered the phone many times:" above does last week here mean the week that ended or the week coninues upto now?  Thiconfuses me. Please help.

Comment: @Policewala Excellent question! Now I see that I wrote that part of the answer without awareness of how much it depended on the reader's understanding subtle Engilsh idioms about time. For simplicity, imagine that the sentence "During the past week, Chris has answered the phone" is said on Monday, with the understanding that "the past week" and "last week" refer to the same seven-day period, ending in the present—even though, as StoneyB said, "the past week" and "last week" don't always refer to the same seven days. I'll try to think of a way to revise my wording in the answer. :)

Comment: @Policewala By the way, it is OK to mention the time interval explicitly with the present perfect, as long as the interval ends in the present (or possibly continues into the future). For example, "I have been waiting **for the last two hours**" or "I have been sitting here **from 4:00 p.m. until now**." It would sound strange, though, to say "I have been sitting here from 4:00 p.m. until 6:00 p.m." even if right now is 6:00 p.m.

Comment: Ben sir,in this phrase of ours "For example, this sentence means that Chris performed the duty of phone-answerer last week, and answered the phone many times:" above does last week here mean the week that ended or the week coninues upto now? Thiconfuses me.I have understood the rest of your explanation.

Comment: @Policewala I intended the reader to imagine that today is the first day of the new week, so "last week" extends up to and including yesterday (but not including today). The time interval can end "just before" the immediate present, as in "Jones has won the race", where the race has "just" finished, a little before the sentence. How long before is acceptable as "just before" varies a lot depending on the topic, which is why there is no simple, thorough explanation of the present perfect.

Comment: @Policewala However, your question has made me understand that the "last week" example requires the reader to already know English ways of talking about time—and is therefore not a clear example! I am going to think about how to rewrite it so it doesn't use the phrase "last week".

Comment: The explanation would be easier to understand if the sentences were contrasted with their past-tense counterparts, whenever possible. Can we say "Brenda worked at Merriam-Webster since 1997."? Does it suggest that she doesn't work there anymore, or is it unknown? Is it possible to say "I saw war", "Jones won the race", "Did you eat lunch?" in the situations you would use their present-perfect counterparts? If it is, does it have a different connotation?

Comment: "A person wouldn't ask that question after the middle of the afternoon, because that would be too much later than the normal time to eat lunch." -- But then if there is a reason to think that they might not have had lunch during the normal time, would one use past or present perfect i.e "Did you eat lunch?" or "Have you eaten lunch?". (My gut feeling is that one could use both.)

Comment: @michau Thanks for the suggestion. I think that's excellent! I'll think about how to revise this answer to include contrasts with past-tense counterparts, hopefully without making it excessively long.

Comment: @lebatsnok Yes: if the expected time foreating lunch got shifted (even for just that one person), you could still say "Have you eaten lunch?" The present perfect just makes a person's brain search for some immediately relevant time interval. And yes, you can also say "Did you eat lunch?" The simple past *always* works. It just leads the listener to think of the event as occurring at a specific time rather than nonspecifically within a time interval.

Comment: Your statement of how the present perfect tense is used in the 1st paragraph of your answer seems a bit confusing to me. In "I have seen war", the event indeed started in the past, but it hasn't continued to the present. If it did, the person would have started seeing war in a point of the past and would not have stopped seeing it for *every second* of her life since then. Also you wrote "maybe more than once during that time interval". If an event started in the past and continued to the present, how could it happen more than once? Either an event is continuous or episodic, it can't be both.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista In "I have seen war", "war" is a mass noun; it means war in general, not a specific war. The sentence as a whole means that the speaker's lifetime experience includes one or more wars, perhaps now on-going and perhaps concluded long ago. Perhaps the speaker's experience includes two or more simultaneous wars. The present perfect tense doesn't specify any of that. It just says that the speaker's lifetime experience somehow includes war. Does that help?

Comment: @BenKovitz Thank you very much for the answer! I understand clearly what the sentence "I have seen war" means. What I was trying to say is that your definition of present perfect ( "present perfect means the action happened at an unstated time during a certain time interval that started in the past and continued to the present" ) does not fit here because the action of seeing war does not happen continuously to the present, it is an episodic event which happened 1-N times during the life of the person and maybe it's also going on now (differently from, e.g. "I have been running for one hour").

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Ah, now I see. I think the subordinate clause, starting with "that", caused confusion. The _time interval_ extends continuously from the past to the present. The _action_ or _actions_ need not extend to the present. The action or actions are "inside" the time interval, perhaps filling it, perhaps scattered within it, perhaps overlapping with it, perhaps occurring only at the very end. (When I wrote that sentence, I was wondering if it might induce this misunderstanding. I'll think about how to make it clearer.)

Comment: +1 I found much here useful and wise. I’ve started a complementary answer of my own. In good part I find it, for myself, more co-exploration than producing answers. I’m marking this in hopes I’ll read yours again more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

PRESENT = now / PERFECT = 100% or complete or finished.

PRESENT PERFECT must have relationship with "now" and "100% status" at the time of speaking.

That's why we say "PRESENT PERFECT"

It has four types of main usage.

1. Experience

> I have been to the United States before. (Now 100% of "experience")

2. Continuation(1. present perfect, 2. present perfect progressive(used when emphasized))

> I have studied English for 10 years / since 1998 (Now 100% of "continuation of 10 years of studying English")

> I have been studying English for 10 years / since 1998 (emphasis on continuation by 'present perfect+progresive')

3. Result/Consequence

> I have lost my key. (Now 100% of result/consequence of"not having the key now (as a result of losing))"

4. Completion

> I have just finished my homework. (Now 100% of "completion of your homework")

Remember that PRESENT means NOW and Perfect means 100% (100% NOW)

'experience' goes well with preposition 'before'

'continuation' goes well with preposition 'for/since'

'completion' goes well with preposition'just/already/yet'

'result/consequence' goes well with verbs 'leave/go/lose' and implies current status as a result of something or some fact.

PAST TENSE MEANS SOMETHING WAS DONE IN THE PAST.

> I lost money. (We know that you lost money in the past. We don't know the exact time because there is no 'time adverb' like yesterday.)

> I have lost money. (We know that you lost money and you don't have it **NOW**. Present perfect implies you have not money **NOW** and this fact can have some impact on your future action because you don't have it **NOW**. We don't know the exact time when you lost it. The focus is **NOW** you don't have it.)

Remember PRESENT PERFECT has relationship with **NOW**, something is **PERFECT**.

That's why it is called "PRESENT PERFECT"

Answer (score 0):

Focus on your purpose.

Use simple past to:

- describe a past action that ended in the past.  (*I **read** an article last week*.)
- describe an event at a specific time.  (I **tried** the quiche at Mary's party.)

Use present perfect to:

- describe events that started in the past but continue at least into the present. (*I **have found** it hard to understand.*  -- i.e. I still do)
- describe an action that has occurred in the past and will occur again (*I **have gone** running every day this week.* -- I will again)
- describe an experience at an unspecified time in the past. (*I **have tried** the quiche. It was great.*)
- describe a recently completed event in combination with the word "just."  (*I **have just tried** the quiche and I am full.*)

Comment: A problem is that even these “rules of thumb” are complex when compared to ordinary discourse. Past action that ended in the past. But: I have eaten snails (once). Specific time. But: I have seen a bear in the wild. It was last 4th of July at a picnic. In the middle of the day. Started in past, continues: I am writing; I quit smoking. Action will recur: I came home. Experience, unspecified time: I loved college. Recently completed event with “just”: I just wet my pants.  — People will say “exceptions”,  but all of my counter-examples are very common. 1/

Comment: Even if the key descriptions were 6 simple “rules” for this one issue, it is not possible to consciously review and select them at the same time we are speaking. And what else do we need to have memorized, call into mind, identify our “purpose” and select from the options? Most native speakers cannot even achieve a “purpose” such as “Introduce yourself for 5 minutes” while avoiding words that are 6 letters long or contain an “n”. 2/

Comment: How could a learner determine the purpose of every utterance, recall and apply rules to make every choice, while also keeping in mind and deciding what they want to say? Not to be personally critical. I’ve carried pretty much the same assumptions most of my life. And such assumptions are held by a large majority of people. But they cannot withstand logical scrutiny nor the scientific evidence. See, eg, http://www.sdkrashen.com/content/books/principles_and_practice.pdf Part IV

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental difference is this:

Past Simple:
When the speaker has in mind (consciously or unconsciously) an ending time boundary for the state, action, event, etc, that the verb names or “is talking about”, or such a terminal end boundary for a time period in which such is anchored, the preterite (simple past tense) is used. The time period or periods may be implicit or explicit.

Something that ended and occurred in a time period that has ended at the time of utterance.

Present Perfect:
When the speaker has in mind that the state, action, event, etc, has no ending time boundary, or does not wish to convey it, or (sometimes) that the consequences or importance of the state, action, event, etc, the present perfect is used.

Something that occurred in the past but in a relevant time period whose termination is not marked.

It is complicated because we might conceptualize something in various ways, for example the meaning or sense of a word or phrase, or how the speaker is thinking about time intervals and how they interrelate.

If I want to convey that I was born, I will very likely say “I was born [+ (optionally) more]”, not “I have been ...” nor “I am” (though both of the latter are possible). The way that we think about the concept, the meaning of the word, is most responsible for this. The consequences of the event are enduring, and the event unsurprisingly remains important to me, but we nearly always think of birth as an event with an end: Once we’ve been evicted.

Someone would be likely to say “I have been baptized”, although if we imagine seeing a baptism in a movie, say, it may seem just as clearly an event with an end. Yet, it is often conceptualized differently: as an event which marks a lasting (perhaps eternal?) transformation.

If we reflect on how these two things are and can be similar, and question a bit deeply, we will find complexity. Is not birth also a transformation with important consequences?

Thus we gain insight into the fact that the human mind perceives and interprets a very complex and very mysterious world in ways that we often take as simple truths about reality.

(Much of this idea was discussed or alluded to in Ben Kibitz’ answer; I will return and see if I can improve on this answer.)

The linguist and scholar Noam Chomsky often says that modern science was born when Galileo and his contemporaries engaged in “a willingness to be puzzled by simple things”. It was once virtually universally obvious that the sun revolves around the earth. The classical Greeks, Aristotle, explained that steam rises and rocks fall to the ground “because things seek to go to their natural place”.

So it is today for most of us with human thought and language: Words do not “refer” to things in the real world. What we call “grammar rules” are not used by the mind-brain to comprehend and produce language. They are attempts to describe aspects of what we do when we externalize thought.

How we do that remains in large part mysterious and may forever be.

Consider: If we hear “a brown house”, how do we know that it’s brown on the exterior? This is not taught, yet 5 year olds know it.

What is a river? We “know”, yet there’s much we can’t explain. If we look away from a river and look back, its “essence” (perhaps) is gone. The water has flowed past and has been replaced. Yet it’s the same river. If it becomes 1% pollution, it’s still a river. 99%? Still. 100%? What if someone throws a teabag in it? Does it carry/contain water or tea?

Ideas from Chomsky. See for example, https://youtu.be/XNSxj0TVeJs. Search “Chomsky language” for many more. He uses somewhat high vocabulary and some of what he says requires some background to understand, but contrary to many, most I’d say, academics/intellectuals, his speech is clear; at least not deliberately designed to be obscure.

How to “learn” to use them? *Don’t study them!* Unless you find grammar to be a compelling area of inquiry for its own sake.

Just listen to and read things you can easily understand and that you truly enjoy. Attend to meaning, not form. Our brains use their own systems, abstract and unconscious, to build a mental representation of a language. We don’t know enough about how this works to “help” it. Humans were “designed”/evolved to acquire language and we cannot help but do it if we receive input that’s interesting and understandable.

Even the simple past is not simple.

Consider “You’re already going to class? I thought it started next week.” Is “started” the simple past tense there?

More: beniko-mason.net
sdkrashen.com
Bill VanPatten podcasts
facebook.com/groups/storylistening

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a simple differentiation.

“I have done” describes *me* (by saying that I have the property of {having done {the thing in question} }).

“I did” makes a historical statement about the past.

(Source:  a book I read once; no idea which one.)