# Simple past or Present perfect with today?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect

Please look at the following sentences and tell me the difference between them.

1. If you *have met him today*, then you must consider yourself lucky.
2. If you *met him today*, then you must consider yourself lucky.

Also,

3. Today, *I've seen your* friend talking to my neighbour.
4. Today, *I saw your* friend talking to my neighbour.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see if this ELL post answers your question: [Is there a simple and clear way to explain the difference between past simple and present perfect?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42951/is-there-a-simple-and-clear-way-to-explain-the-difference-between-past-simple-an?rq=1)

Comment: You should explain why you want to use present perfect in your examples. In short examples without context, there may not be enough information to decide.

Answer (score 1):

When using the *present perfect*, basically we're implying that the day is not over yet. So you could see someone talking in the morning, noon or night.

However, when using the *past simple* we imply that some *period* of the day ended, namely:

> Today, I saw your friend talking to my neighbour.
>   (Earlier this morning, for example.)