# Understanding the Present Perfect Tense: An Advanced Question

Tags: present-perfect

Consider the sentence: "I have read the book you recommended." This statement clearly indicates that the action of reading the book is complete, yet it does not specify when this action occurred, only that it has relevance to the present moment.

Given this context, my question is: How does the use of the present perfect tense in such a statement influence the interpretation of the action's relevance to the present, compared to if the past simple tense were used? Furthermore, how does this usage impact the listener's understanding of the action's completion and its significance to the current discourse?

Comment: It isn't clear from the example sentence whether the book was read before, or as a result of, the recommendation. The speaker could clarify it by saying "I have already read..." or "I have just read..."

Comment: I wonder why you are asking this since you must have taught it. Right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Present Perfect sometimes interpreted as "past action with indefeinite time span"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/243406/why-present-perfect-sometimes-interpreted-as-past-action-with-indefeinite-time)

Comment: Closely related: [i have thought or i thought?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90266/i-have-thought-or-i-thought), and with an astounding 192,000 views: [“I saw a dog” vs. “I have seen a dog”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42968/i-saw-a-dog-vs-i-have-seen-a-dog)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“I saw a dog” vs. “I have seen a dog”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42968/i-saw-a-dog-vs-i-have-seen-a-dog)

Comment: You answered your own question. With the present perfect the past time situation is conceived as having some kind of current relevance, relevance to the present, whereas the preterite does not express any such relationship. Beyond that depends on context etc.

Answer (score 0):

"I have read the book you recommended." [at some unspecified moment in the past, as I know say this]

"I read the book you recommended." [implies you finished it at a specific time in the past *even if not stated outrightly*, last year, last week, two months ago].

This question has been answered multiple times in this forum so it is probably a duplicate.