# Why was the simple past instead of the present perfect used?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple

I have found the following sentence in Michael Swan's grammar book.

> From his earliest childhood, he **loved** music.

So far as I know, **present perfect** is used to talk about **actions that have just completed** (such as "He has just/already come") or if the action is still continuing and which began in the past ("He has lived in the house for the last five years.")

On the other hand, the  **simple past** is used to talk about completed actions **in the past,** such as "He saw the film yesterday," or "Columbus discovered America".

- Why did the author use the simple past instead of present tense? Is it a grammatical rule, or usage?

If I change the sentence  into present perfect and present perfect continuous,will they be grammatically wrong and unidiomatic?

> From his childhood, he **has loved** music

from his earliest childhood, he has been loving music

Comment: If you're asking if the present perfect is *grammatical*, see ["Q: Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000) and ["Is there a simple and clear way to explain the difference between past simple and present perfect?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42951/is-there-a-simple-and-clear-way-to-explain-the-difference-between-past-simple-an). If you're asking *why* the author chose the simple past, we'd need context or to ask them.

Comment: @JasonBassford.i am sorry i can not contact Swan.please let others give their answers

Comment: What I'm saying is that anybody answering *why* Swan said something, without more context than is given here, would be entirely speculative. If you quote more from the book than the single sentence, it might be more objectively answerable. Especially since it's a grammar book, it's likely the reason is clear, given the page on which it appears, assuming that it's an example sentence that's being used to demonstrate something about grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the man is no longer alive.

> From his earliest childhood, he loved music.

Now consider that we are talking about someone who is sitting next to us:

> He has loved music since his earliest childhood.
>
> From his earliest childhood, he has loved music.
>
> From his earliest childhood, he loved music.  But recently he was diagnosed with melophobia.

Comment: Perhaps the subject ***no longer*** has that love of music, even though he's not dead.

Comment: melophobia- fear of music. (Nor a word I expect to ever use again.)

Comment: @Patriot.thank  you.when i read the sentence,I felt that the music lover was .no more

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao  Perhaps he is no longer with us:  "From his earliest childhood, he loved music."