# Past and present perfect

Tags: tense

These are two definitions of the word ‘no-show’, which one is better and why? And what is the difference between past and present perfect?

> A ‘no-show’ is an informal expression for someone who **has bought** a ticket for an event, a journey, etc.; but who **hasn’t come** to the event.

> A ‘no-show’ is an informal expression for someone who **bought** a ticket for an event, a journey, etc.; but who **didn’t come** to the event.

Comment: The first one is perhaps more natural, because it expresses the point of view of the staff at the event. The tense doesn't really matter, though. You could also use the present tense - _someone who buys a ticket... but doesn't attend the event_.

Comment: Do you know the difference between simple past and present perfect generally? If so, what are you unsure about in these examples?

Comment: There are tons of answers on the difference between the two on this site. That said, here is the usage for the present perfect: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple and clear way to explain the difference between past simple and present perfect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42951/is-there-a-simple-and-clear-way-to-explain-the-difference-between-past-simple-an)